# A table insert fails during replication with "Incorrect datetime value" but same statement will insert fine manually

Tags: replication, mariadb, errors

I have a two server master-master arrangement running under High Availability on RHEL7. One server is the active server and the other is passive.  Only the active server is doing any writing, the passive simply receives updates near real-time so that its database is ready if the active one takes a spill.

Two weeks ago, I had a server crash and it corrupted a RAID10 disk, clobbered a super block and nothing would recover it.  I brought in another server, built it out, backed up the running server's databases using `--master-data --single-transaction --all-databases`, restored them to new server.  All went well.

When I started the new slave, I started getting the "Incorrect datetime value" errors.  It struck me as strange that it could be inserted into one database, but not the other one.

Bother servers are running the same RHEL7 and Server version: 5.5.68-MariaDB MariaDB Server.

Here is the error as seen in replication:

```
MariaDB [sws_db]> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: server5.deleted.com
                  Master_User: maria_repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: server5-binlog.000244
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 992862680
               Relay_Log_File: server4-relaylog.000091
                Relay_Log_Pos: 24877279
        Relay_Master_Log_File: server5-binlog.000244
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: bsg_db,cf_db,etg_db,sms_db,sws_db
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: archive_bsg_db,archive_cf_db,archive_etg_db,archive_sws_db
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1292
                   Last_Error: **Error 'Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 00:00:01.0'** for column 'eventTime' at row 1' on query. Default database: 'sws_db'. Query: 'INSERT into events (deviceId, eventNbr, eventTime, latitude, longitude, speed, gpsNav, direction, totalTripTime, accIdleTime, accTravelDistance, dbInsertTime, sensor, compassHeading, streetAddress, cityStateZip, geoSlot, perimeterName, sequenceNbr, eAreaName, voltage, accIgnitionOnTime, altitude, loggedDataIndicated, currentOdometer, acceleration, deceleration, rpm, avgFuelConsumption, fuelLevel, cellIdUsed, cellIdAccuracy, gpsHdop, stateAbbrev, backupBatteryVoltage, powerUpReason, garminSpecialRequest, gpsLock, vin) VALUES ('865918060293591', 551, '1970-01-01 00:00:01.0', '33.612186', '-86.624699', 0, 0, 'N', 0, 0, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0, 352, '1865 Gadsden Hwy, BIRMINGHAM, AL 35235, US', '', 0, '', 25530, '', '', 0, 235, 'N', 10686.151, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, '', 0.0, 0, 'AL', '', '', 'R','', '')'
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 637795419
              Relay_Log_Space: 50013051989
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1292
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 00:00:01.0' for column 'eventTime' at row 1' on query. Default database: 'sws_db'. Query: 'INSERT into events (deviceId, eventNbr, eventTime, latitude, longitude, speed, gpsNav, direction, totalTripTime, accIdleTime, accTravelDistance, dbInsertTime, sensor, compassHeading, streetAddress, cityStateZip, geoSlot, perimeterName, sequenceNbr, eAreaName, voltage, accIgnitionOnTime, altitude, loggedDataIndicated, currentOdometer, acceleration, deceleration, rpm, avgFuelConsumption, fuelLevel, cellIdUsed, cellIdAccuracy, gpsHdop, stateAbbrev, backupBatteryVoltage, powerUpReason, garminSpecialRequest, gpsLock, vin) VALUES ('865918060293591', 551, '1970-01-01 00:00:01.0', '33.612186', '-86.624699', 0, 0, 'N', 0, 0, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0, 352, '1865 Gadsden Hwy, BIRMINGHAM, AL 35235, US', '', 0, '', 25530, '', '', 0, 235, 'N', 10686.151, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, '', 0.0, 0, 'AL', '', '', 'R','', '')'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 2
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is VERY odd is that I can copy that same statement from the above output and it will insert without issue.

```
MariaDB [sws_db]> INSERT into events (deviceId, eventNbr, eventTime, latitude, longitude, speed, gpsNav, direction, totalTripTime, accIdleTime, accTravelDistance, dbInsertTime, sensor, compassHeading, streetAddress, cityStateZip, geoSlot, perimeterName, sequenceNbr, eAreaName, voltage, accIgnitionOnTime, altitude, loggedDataIndicated, currentOdometer, acceleration, deceleration, rpm, avgFuelConsumption, fuelLevel, cellIdUsed, cellIdAccuracy, gpsHdop, stateAbbrev, backupBatteryVoltage, powerUpReason, garminSpecialRequest, gpsLock, vin) VALUES ('865918060293591', 551, '1970-01-01 00:00:01.0', '33.612186', '-86.624699', 0, 0, 'N', 0, 0, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0, 352, '1865 Gadsden Hwy, BIRMINGHAM, AL 35235, US', '', 0, '', 25530, '', '', 0, 235, 'N', 10686.151, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, '', 0.0, 0, 'AL', '', '', 'R','', '');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sws_db]> select * from events where deviceId='865918060293591';
+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------------+---------+-------------+----------------------+---------------+----------------------+---------+------+
| deviceId        | latitude  | longitude  | dbInsertTime        | eventTime           | speed | gpsNav | direction | sensor | eventNbr | totalTripTime | accIdleTime | accTravelDistance | compassHeading | streetAddress                              | cityStateZip | geoSlot | perimeterName | sequenceNbr | eAreaName | voltage | accIgnitionOnTime | altitude | loggedDataIndicated | acceleration | deceleration | rpm  | avgFuelConsumption | fuelLevel | currentOdometer | cellIdUsed | cellIdAccuracy | gpsHdop | stateAbbrev | backupBatteryVoltage | powerUpReason | garminSpecialRequest | gpsLock | vin  |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------------+---------+-------------+----------------------+---------------+----------------------+---------+------+
| 865918060293591 | 33.612186 | -86.624699 | 2024-01-18 17:34:08 | 1970-01-01 00:00:01 |     0 |      0 | N         |      0 |      551 |             0 |           0 |                 0 |            352 | 1865 Gadsden Hwy, BIRMINGHAM, AL 35235, US |              |       0 |               |       25530 |           |         |                 0 |      235 | N                   |            0 |            0 |    0 |                0.0 |       0.0 |         10686.2 |            |            0.0 |       0 | AL          |                      |               | R                    |         |      |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------------+---------+-------------+----------------------+---------------+----------------------+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I compared things that I could google and that seemed appropriate on both servers and they are the same. Such as:

```
@@global.time_zone = SYSTEM
innodb_strict_mode = OFF
sql_mode = (there is no value assigned)
```

What might cause this behavior?

Comment: Maybe [MDEV-28229](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28229) `mysql56_temporal_format` needs to be normalized on the import and replication.